# Remover elemento da página com javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e me surgiu uma dúvida:

**Tem como eu remover um elemento de uma página com javascript sem usar a gambiarra do `innerHTML = ''`?**

Por exemplo, eu quero remover uma div (como a do exemplo abaixo) e todo seu conteúdo:

```
<div id="conteudo">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso com Javascript puro?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Você pode usar [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild?redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.removeChild)

Note que, para remover o nó (e não somente o conteúdo do mesmo), você precisa antes recuperar o pai deste nó:

```
// Removendo um nó a partir do pai
var node = document.getElementById("conteudo");
if (node.parentNode) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Coloquei o link para versão em português da documentação do Node.removeChild na Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre usar esse código que você me passou e esse: document.getElementById('conteudo').remove() ?

Comment: O método remove() **NÃO** é suportado por todos os browsers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove#Browser_compatibility

Nessa lista você pode ver que o Internet Explorer e o Safari **não** suportam essa método.

Dependendo do que sua aplicação faz e dos clientes da mesma, isso pode lhe causar muitos problemas no futuro.

Comment: Valeu por esclarecer, vou usar esse exemplo que você sugeriu e dar uma estudada a respeito

Answer (score 6):

Assim:

```
var el = document.getElementById( 'conteudo' );
el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
```

Answer (score 4):

É simples:

```js
document.getElementById('conteudo').remove()
```

Comment: Está correto, funcionou certinho, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: De nada @Odair porém te dou um aviso: testei agora no Internet Explorer e ele não tem suporte ao método `.remove`

Comment: O método remove() NÃO é suportado por todos os browsers como você pode ver [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove#Browser_compatibility).  Essa lista mostra que o Internet Explorer e o Safari não suportam essa método.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode remover um elemento filho de outro com o seguinte código, que, no caso, foi utilizado para remover um elemento "`<button>`" que está em "`<body>`"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>oiii</div><!---Esse div é so pra atrapalhar--->
<button>Oláa</button>
<script>
button.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
document.body.removeChild(document.body.querySelector("button"))})
//quando você clicar no botão, o mesmo será deletado
</script>
</body>
</html>
```