# Remover Apenas um Item de uma lista javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde senhores, tenho um elemento que cria varios itens em uma lista.

```js
function addParagrafo() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("lista-paragrafos");
  var conteudo = document.getElementById("paragrafo").value;
  ul.innerHTML += "<div class='panel-body'><li>" + conteudo + "<br><br> <div class ='col-xs-12'><button type='button' class='btn-remover btn-default'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i> Remover</button><button type='button' class='btn-tabelas btn-primary' ><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Tabelas</button><button type='button' class='btn-imagens btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Imagens</button></div></li></div>";

  var lis = document.getElementById("lista-paragrafos").getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var list = lis[i].className = 'itens-checklist:' + i;
  }
  var btn = ul.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].className += ' pull-right btn btn-xs btn-checklist: ' + list;
  }


}
```

```html
<ul id="lista-paragrafos">
</ul>
<div class="panel-body">
  <textarea rows="3" id="paragrafo" name="checklist" class="form-control "></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-default pull-right" title="Adicionar este parágrafo" onclick="addParagrafo()"><i class="fa fa-plus">Adcionar</i>
  </button>
  <span class="help-block">Digite ou altere o objeto referente aos documentos da sua inspeção.</span>
```

Porem eu preciso clicar em "Remover" e ele exclui o proprio objeto, estou tendo dificuldades pra solucionar isso, então gostaria de uma luz pois comecei a 'programar' a pouco tempo e não achei nada realmente explicativo em javascript, apenas em jquery.

Comment: Tem uma coisa pra consertar antes de resolver isso: os `<li>` precisam ser o primeiro nível abaixo do `<ul>`, não pode ter `<div>` entre eles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar essa [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4608/14262):

```
  var node = document.getElementById(id);
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
```

E então é só colocar um `id` na `div` que possui o conteúdo que você esta adicionando dinamicamente, algo mais ou menos assim:

`<div id='div"+k+"' class='panel-body'>`

E por fim referenciar essa `div` no `onclick` do botão remover:

`<button type='button' class='btn-remover btn-default' onclick='delParagrafo("+k+")'>`

```js
var k = 0;

function addParagrafo() {
  k++;
  var ul = document.getElementById("lista-paragrafos");
  var conteudo = document.getElementById("paragrafo").value;
  ul.innerHTML += "<div id='div"+k+"' class='panel-body'><li>" + conteudo + "<br><br> <div class ='col-xs-12'><button type='button' class='btn-remover btn-default' onclick='delParagrafo("+k+")'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i> Remover</button><button type='button' class='btn-tabelas btn-primary' ><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Tabelas</button><button type='button' class='btn-imagens btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Imagens</button></div></li></div>";

  var lis = document.getElementById("lista-paragrafos").getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var list = lis[i].className = 'itens-checklist:' + i;
  }
  var btn = ul.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].className += ' pull-right btn btn-xs btn-checklist: ' + list;
  }
}

function delParagrafo(id){
  var node = document.getElementById("div"+id);
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista-paragrafos">
</ul>
<div class="panel-body">
  <textarea rows="3" id="paragrafo" name="checklist" class="form-control "></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-default pull-right" title="Adicionar este parágrafo" onclick="addParagrafo()"><i class="fa fa-plus">Adcionar</i>
  </button>
  <span class="help-block">Digite ou altere o objeto referente aos documentos da sua inspeção.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que os botões que estás a juntar têm uma classe `btn-remover` podias usar isso para saber qual o elemento pai desse conteúdo (que é aquele que tem a classe `panel-body`) e apagá-lo.

Podias fazer um delegador de eventos, e uma função que vai buscar esse elemento pai assim:

```
function closest(el, cssClass) {
    while (el = el.parentNode){
        if (el.classList.contains(cssClass)) return el;
    }
    return false;
}
document.getElementById('lista-paragrafos').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-remover')){
        var panelBody = closest(e.target, 'panel-body');
        panelBody.parentNode.removeChild(panelBody);
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njortae9/